# How to retrieve all unanswered Q(uestion)?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I develop an questions/answers module (little like StackOverflow but for another theme) in Symfony2/Doctrine2.

I just want retrieve all questions who don't have answer. I've two tables, question, and answer (who have question_id). How can I do that in DQL/ Doctrine?

QUESTION

-id

-author

-date

-content

-...

ANSWER

-id

-author

-date

-content

-**question_id**

---

- I've try NOT in, but it's don't seems to work in DQL.
- I try a little trick with LEFT JOIN on question and a always false condition (WHERE q.id < 0)
- I try with COUNT(), but I need all row result, and MySql don't return row for COUNT(q.reponses) who don't exist...

Any help appreciate!

Thanks

Comment: You need to show your table structure. It's hard to tell you what to query, without seeing your data.

Comment: Datastructure is very simple, but I edit for bein more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference to the "little trick with left join" is the right answer, except you are testing the wrong column - you need to check if the *answer* is null:

```
select q.*
from question q
left join answer a on a.question_id = q.id
where a.question_id is null
```

Actually you can test any column in the left joined table being null (since they will all be null if the join fails), but I tend to check for the same column I'm joining on so the optimizer has to deal with as few columns as possible.